# why there are margins under every text in my application on mobile browser only?

Tags: css, media-queries, mobile-safari

Edit:
The problem was happening because of the font itself. (Tajawal)

I am developing an application using HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

The problem is that I am seeing small spaces like margins under every text in my application appear only on a mobile phone browser or PWA.

I am not seeing these spaces while developing on my computer on different screen sizes using Chrome dev tools. it appears only on a mobile.

HTML elements are very simple, like the following:

```
<button class="m-0">
    this is button
</button>
```

[image]

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: Changing the font solved the problem.